# JQuery: Replacing <br /> with a delimiter when grabbing .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to grab some text from an HTML element that is formed like this:

```
<td>
  <br>
  48 main Ave
  <br>
  Virginia, VA 23000
  <br>
  (800) 789-7898
</td>
```

The problem is keeping the format, or some sort of separation between the lines (it can be any sort of delimiter, but something to show the break). I can't simply use .text():

```
$('td').text()
// 48 main AveVirginia, VA 23000(800) 789-7898
```

Nor can I use .html() because there is actually a bunch of other junk in the .

Is there any other creative way I may be able to either keep the line break in OR place some sort of delimiter where the 
 tag is?

Thanks!

EDIT: First off, you guys are awesome! Thanks for taking the time to respond, all of you.

I think using replace is the way to go. But I find once I've done that, I'm not able to grab the text any more. Here is my full code:

```
detailsArray = [];
$("tr[id*=Row]").each(function(index){

    type = $(this).attr("type");
    id = $(this).attr("idtag");

    if (id){
        $("div[detail*="+id+"] tr td").each(function(index){
            var content = $(this).html();
            content = content.replace(/<br>/g,'|'); 
            $(this).replaceWith(content);
            detailsArray 
                .push(type+', '+ $(this)
                  .text()
                );
        })
     }
});
```

The problem is, the $(this).text() doesn't capture the change. So I tried breaking it out into two different portions, like so:

```
detailsArray = [];
$("tr[id*=Row]").each(function(index){

    type = $(this).attr("type");
    id = $(this).attr("idtag");

    if (id){
         //First we change it around
         $("div[detail*="+id+"] tr td").each(function(index){
            var content = $(this).html();
            content = content.replace(/<br>/g,'|'); 
            $(this).replaceWith(content);
         }
        //Then we grab it
        $("div[detail*="+id+"] tr td").each(function(index){
            detailsArray 
                .push(type+', '+ $(this)
                  .text()
                );
        })
     }
});
```

I see the change happen on the page, but now the grab portion comes up empty. detailsArray = [].

So how can I use this? Thanks!

EDIT** Thought a better look at the html would help:

```
<div detail="27fdgd68_4_B_">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="size2">    
    <tbody>
      <tr bgcolor="#FFF5CC">
        <td>
          <b>
            <a target="_blank" href="" onclick="script()">Big Properties</a>
          </b>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bigproperties.com"></a>
          <br>
          48 main Ave
          <br>
          Virginia, VA 23000
          <br>
          (800) 789-7898
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Again, the goal is to get the following text (assuming a '|' delimiter):

48 main Ave|Virginia, VA 23000|(800) 789-7898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Example of using it:

```
var content = $('myElement').html();
content = content.replace(/<br>/g,',');
```

To update html code use jQuery function [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
$(".yourDivClass").replaceWith(content);
```

```js
var content = $("div").html();
content = content.replace(/<br>/g,','); 

$("div").replaceWith(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <br/>
  4884 Travertine Ave
    <br/>
  Virginia Beach, VA 23462
    <br/>
  (757) 605-5234
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer that. I updated it, check now

Comment: @tehnuty, I meant the very first line. How will he set the var = content? See this https://jsfiddle.net/g8h49jkg/, using html() doesnt work

Comment: @RickHitchcock thanks for noticing.Totally forgot about it! Updated answer

Comment: nice, btw I suggest putting it in a snippet so others can see it directly

Comment: I think this is the way to go. I'm getting a bit of an error, however. See my edits above.

Comment: I can't really understand what are you trying to do here. Have you tried using .html() ?

Comment: html() just pours out all of the elements. I simply want the text portion. But the text all comes as one string, so it's difficult to format it later. I'd prefer to have some sort of delimiter in between so that I can differentiate between the lines

Comment: Are you maybe looking for .split() method? yourcontent.split(','); <- put here delimiter you are working with.

Comment: Eventually I'll split it. The problem is getting that delimiter into the text line to begin with. I've added a final sentence to my question which shows the desired output. I've also shown the full html. What should the JQuery script look like to get that result from the html? Apologies that I haven't been clear! You've been very helpful so far

Comment: Almost. The idea is to capture that text in a variable with which my function will return. The idea is to push that text into detailsArray, which is what I had trouble with. But I guess this is close enough that I can probably figure it out form here...

Answer (score 1):

I think the separation is there but you cannot see it in the browser, otherwise this alert here would not show on separate lines.

```js
alert($('td').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
<td>
  <br>
  4884 Travertine Ave
  <br>
  Virginia Beach, VA 23462
  <br>
  (757) 605-5234
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do `$('td').html.replace(/\<br>/g, '|'))` to replace all the `<br>` tags with a pipe symbol (or any other delimiter you like).
Depending on how you plan to use the grabbed data, there can be more elegant solutions.